# Can UTF-8 contain zero byte in the middle?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

UTF-8 uses 1-4 bytes for each character. Here is 4-byte character 
So in Python 2, `len('') == 4` and in JavaScript `encodeURI('') === "%F0%9F%90%8D"`.
The question is, can UTF-8 contain a zero byte in the middle?

For example, the first Russian letter `А` consists of 2 bytes: `0xD0, 0x90`.
May there exist a letter that has **not leading zero or zero in the middle**, like this `0xAB, 0, 0xCD`?

Comment: Some very simple and quick research (like reading [the UTF-8 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)) would have given you the answer easily.

Comment: And why are you asking? Is it just curiosity, or do you have some other problem underpinning this question? If you have some other underlying problem, please ask about it directly instead.

Comment: I have read that post, purhaps did not notice not leading zero.

Comment: My task is much complicated to explain and requires C++ knowledge. If you still want to know, here it is: I want to keep long tables `char table[128*5]`
that maps any character from ISO8859-X to UTF-8. For each request of a special character, I need to return a pointer to that in a corresponding table. Since the first 128 characters in each ISO8859-X are ASCI ones, I am able to save half of memory, hence 256-128=128 instead of 256.

Comment: I know that there are 3-byte like `№` (`0xF0` in ISO8859-5 Numero sign). The next question is if there are no 4-byte ones. If there are no, I can keep `table[128*4]` knowing that there is always a terminated character. Otherwise, I have to allocate an extra 0 byte for safe reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only zero byte in a valid UTF-8 stream would be a representation of U+0000 NULL, which is just `00` (hex) in UTF-8.

No valid encoding of any other character in UTF-8 will produce a full byte without any bits set.

In other words: if your input characters does not contain the NULL character, then your output byte stream is guaranteed to not contain any zero bytes.